# Turn off (Disable) individual API in API Gateway temporarily without Deleting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

**Is it possible in AWS API Gateway to "turn off"/"disable" an API in API Gateway, without deleting the API itself?**  I'm hoping to keep the configuration of an API, without losing it through the otherwise deletion I'm hoping to avoid; that would also have the beneficial parallel motivation of preventing AWS billed API usage.

Is it possible, or is delete the only option?

Comment: Just in case someone's trying to effectively "turn off" a Lambda-backed API - note that you can also set a throttle on the underlying Lambda as well (`put-function-concurrency`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no disable button, but there are **two possibilities** that can be considered as a workaround:

1. Delete the API stage(s). Without stage, API wont be accessible.
2. Since one can be problematic if there are multiple stages with lots of custom setttings, you can add `Deny` resource base policy to the API.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "execute-api:/{{stageNameOrWildcard}}/{{httpVerbOrWildcard}}/{{resourcePathOrWildcard}}"
        }
    ]
}
```

The policy will Deny all invocations of the API, making it effectively disabled. But the invocations will still count towards API usage.

Comment: Thanks for this; will probably accept this if there are no other Answers after a few days..  "Deny" sounds like a decent partial solution, given there is no actual disable.  Sounds like the only way to avoid requests/invocations from counting toward (billed) API usage, is unfortunately to indeed delete the stage.

Comment: Of course configuration as code capturing an API or stage's config would be the robust solution, which would mostly mitigate the downside of [1.] deleting.

Comment: @cellepo If you have your API in CloudFormation template, you can fully delete it, and then recreate when needed.

Comment: Note: don't forget to re-deploy you API after updating the policy: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-create-attach.html. Also, there will likely be a lag between deployment and propagation of the change. Emperically I observed around 12 seconds lag before the "Deny" came into effect.

Answer (score 13):

you can set the Burst limit / Rate limit for your stage to zero.
In the console: API Gateway -> select API -> Protect/Throttling -> select your stage -> EDIT Default route throttling -> Burst limit=0, Rate limit=0

Works at least for me. When calling the API you get:

{"message":"Too Many Requests"}

Comment: Brilliant, this works for HTTP APIs too which don't have stages

Comment: I also like how this setting becomes effective immediately after clicking the Save button.

Comment: u still get charged though or not?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following as a workaround:

1. You can simply limit the **Usage Plans** of that specific API by activating **Enable Quota** and setting it to (1 request per month) for instance.
   [image]
2. Then optionally under **Gateway Responses,** you can remap the Quota Exceeded response to 500.
   [image]
3. The last step for the changes to take place, Go to Resources then click **actions**,  **Deploy API** then pick the stage and click **Deploy**.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about your credit card being attached to your personal AWS account for trial tier access and a bot finding your gateway and conducting a DOS attack on it, but you're actively developing, you can still throttle back your API Gateway responsiveness by navigating to `API Gateway` > choose your API > `Stages` > choose your stage.  Then make the following adjustments:

- ensure throttling checkbox is checked
- set the rate to 10 requests per second (or lower, not 0)
- set the burst to 5 requests (or lower, not 0)
- `Save` the changes

You'll have to do this for each of the stages of your APIs.

Redeploy your API(s).

If you exceed thresholds Amazon will likely hold you liable for the charges - even if they weren't your own requests against your endpoint.

See also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-free-tier.html#avoid-charges-after-free-tier

Comment: Is this any different from the (as-of-now) [top-rated Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68789404/1357094) from @Werner earlier?

Comment: If you're going for a total block, the best is to just delete the API Gateway you have setup.  If you're actively developing then use the approach in this answer.  If you're in a standby mode, go with @Werner's solution, then you can still revive the API when you come back to it later.  You may also need to disable any EC2 and/or Amplify hosting you have.

Answer (score 0):

There seems a simpler answer than the ones above:

1. settings -> default endpoint -> disabled -> save changes
2. resources -> actions -> deploy